# Why is my for loop exiting after the first element when checking vowels? Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I am new to for loops and enhanced for loops so perhaps someone can help clarify why exactly my enhanced for loop for checking vowels is only checking the first element before exiting the loop?

I put a println(vowel) underneath the for loop to test its output before checking against the input and it is only pulling 'A'. The consonants all work just fine, so I'm more than a little confused at this point.

Anything that can point me in the right direction to figuring or this out or help me understand would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordStart {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

    char[] consonants = {'B','C','D','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
    char[] vowels = {'A','E','I','O','U'};
    System.out.println("Please enter a word: ");
    String word=in.nextLine();
    char firstLetter=(Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)));
    int found = -1;




    for (char vowel: vowels)
{//System.out.println(vowel);
        if (firstLetter == vowel)
    {
        found = 1;
            if (found==1)
            {
                System.out.print(firstLetter+" is a vowel.\n");
                System.exit(0);
            }

    }
     for (char consonant: consonants)   
        {
            if (firstLetter == consonant)
            {
            found = 2;
                {
                    if (found==2)
                    {
                        System.out.print(firstLetter+" is a consonant.\n");
                        System.exit(0);

                    }

                }
            }    
        }
     if (found<=0)
     {
         System.out.println(firstLetter+" is not a vowel or consonant.\n");
         System.exit(0);
     }

}
```

This is the correct code:

import java.util.Scanner;
public class WordStart {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

    char[] consonants = {'B','C','D','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
    char[] vowels = {'A','E','I','O','U'};
    System.out.println("Please enter a word: ");
    String word=in.nextLine();
    char firstLetter=(Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)));
    int found=0;

    for (char vowel:vowels)
    {
        if(firstLetter==vowel)
        {
            found=1;
            System.out.println(firstLetter+" is a vowel.");
            System.exit(0);

        }
    }

     for (char consonant: consonants)   
        {
            if (firstLetter == consonant)
            {
            found = 2;
            System.out.print(firstLetter+" is a consonant.\n");
            System.exit(0);
            }    
        }
     if (found<=0)
     {
         System.out.println(firstLetter+" is not a vowel or consonant.\n");
         System.exit(0);
     }       
}
```

}

The formatting was simply incorrect. After cleaning up the code I found that the problem was with my own carelessness.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: because you find the vowel and so found gets set to 1 and then you check if found == 1 therefore you always exit... take out the System.exit(0)

Comment: I don't entirely understand what your problem is, but you're calling `System.exit(0);`, which will exit the program. Also, what's the point of `found`? You're setting it, then immediately checking if it's what you just set it to.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I see what you're saying. How's the above code instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove `System.exit(0);` statements if you want your program to continue execution.

Try replacing

`System.exit(0);`

with

`break;`

It will stop the execution of current `for` loop and start with next loop.